# Relationship between MAC address and device

Tags: mac-address

Using a device to find its MAC address is easy, but using a MAC address to find its mother/father (the device which owns the MAC address) is possible? If it is, how?

Notes: I had set up a DoS Protection on my router and it had caught a MAC address into the blacklist. I am not sure how to find the host with the MAC address.

Comment: Find the host? You mean its geographical location?

Comment: Besides, blacklisting MAC addresses (especially for stopping DoS) doesn't make sense to me. I can hardly think of a scenario in which it does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question us a bit unclear, but maybe this will help.

MAC addresses are (meant to be) globally unique per network interface.  The first 6 characters (ie 3 bytes) of the MAC address are typically registered to a vendor, and can be looked up. The remaining part  AFAIK is unspecofied. (Id say random, only its fairly common to get sequential numbers of cards from the same batch)

It is worth pointing out that its often possible to change/fake a MAC address, so thr lookups to the manuafacturer are a guide only.

Comment: My stupid router just caught two things in the blacklist - LAN IP(192.168.0.107) and MAC address. I know someone who connected to the router but I don't know who it is.

Comment: So, it isn't possible to find the host (the device) only using the MAC address as it can be change and change and change.

Comment: MAC addresses are normally static, and the first 6 numbers/letters can give you a clue.